# Disabling partial HTML indentation in Vim

Tags: indentation, filetype-html

Caveat: I'm not a web developer.

That being said, there are rare occasions where I have to edit HTML. When I do, I've noticed a behavior in Vim that I don't like, and hope that I can change via configuration.

When I code, I tend to wrap lines at 80 characters. This often means that I have to split HTML tags across lines. What I'd like is some sensible indentation when this happens. So, for example, I might have the following code and would like it indented similarly:

```
<a href="http://someverylongurl.com/foo/bar/blaz/SinwzvO.jpg"><img
   src="http://someverylongurl.com/foo/bar/blaz/Sinwzv0.jpg"
   class="ri" alt="This is an image"></a>
```

But, by default, Vim's autoindentation will indent the split HTML tags to the same level as the HTML tag start on the previous line. In other words, I get something like the following:

```
<a href="http://someverylongurl.com/foo/bar/blaz/SinwzvO.jpg"><img
                                                              src="http://someverylongurl.com/foo/bar/blaz/Sinwzv0.jpg"
                                                              class="ri" alt="This is an image"></a>
```

Which is, exactly, what I don't want. As I'm typing, I find I'm *constantly* having to go back and fix indentations like this.

I like Vim's autoindent generally, and don't want to simply disable it universally. I'd rather just disable or change the split HTML tag indentation, but I can't figure out how.

Is it possible to change this?

(I've tried searching Stackoverflow for this question, but couldn't find it. If it's a duplicate, please point me to the original.)

EDIT: Solution was found here https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3ogbna/disabling_partial_html_indentation_in_vim/cvy8p3u

EDIT #2: Okay, the above solution didn't solve the problem. It's still there.

Comment: I find surprising the indentation example that you gave in the last snippet: I have tried it on my vanilla Homebrew installation (version 7.4) and it workes as I expected: when I hit <Enter> at the end of the line, with `autoindent` enabled vim indents the next line as the line that I just ended. So my guess is that you may have a plugin that alters the default indentation model.

Comment: @VladGURDIGA, yes, I'm starting to suspect that. I'll have to dive into my vimrc and see what I can come up with. My vimrc is here, btw https://github.com/criswell/meh/blob/master/vim/.vimrc

Comment: also check ~/.vim/ since whatever is there is are also loaded, usually ftplugins, colors and other autoload things. 8-)

Comment: I also asked on reddit, and got this answer, which turned out to fix it https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3ogbna/disabling_partial_html_indentation_in_vim/cvy8p3u . I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: Alright... that didn't solve it after all.. The problem is still there. Argh.

Comment: I’m wondering if you tried to look through the output of [:scriptnames](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:scriptnames). I mean I would try to look through the files and try to exclude them one by one.

But before, I’d try `vim -u NONE` to skip rc files at all.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend the [tidy-html5](https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5) plugin.

---

As a web developer myself, I also recommend aligning the HTML tags a little differently,

[AirBnb React Styleguide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#alignment) (most legible & recommended for React)

```
<a href="http://someverylongurl.com/foo/bar/blaz/SinwzvO.jpg">
  <img
    src="http://someverylongurl.com/foo/bar/blaz/Sinwzv0.jpg"
    class="ri"
    alt="This is an image"
  >
</a>
```

[Google HTML Styleguide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#HTML_Line-Wrapping)

```
<a href="http://someverylongurl.com/foo/bar/blaz/SinwzvO.jpg">
  <img src="http://someverylongurl.com/foo/bar/blaz/Sinwzv0.jpg"
       class="ri" alt="This is an image">
</a>
```

This will really help formatters avoid crazy indentations.